# Looking for a remote flash trigger for Sony

Tags: flash, sony, remote, triggers, strobist

Can anyone recommend a wireless flash set up for Sony A200 camera/Sony F58-AM flash unit?

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the pop-up as a trigger; it will provide TTL control of the F58-AM. The only thing you're missing, really, is the off-camera shoe (to mount it on a lightstand) and that's the same unit as the Minolta/KonicaMinolta OC-1, so you may be able to pick one up fairly cheaply on the used market. If you don't want the on-camera flash to influence the lighting, you can put a bit of card in front of it (it doesn't have to be white card) -- as long as even a little bit of light leaks from the pop-up, it should be enough to control the remote flash.

Comment: Not too happy with the reliability of this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only TTL alternative is to go wired. There is a PC adapter that will let you use standard third-party wireless equipment, but it doesn't have a shoe (it's meant for studio lighting) so you'd need to McGuyver a kit together at both ends (camera and flash) to make it work. Minolta's pro solution (on the 9/9000 series cameras) used an on-camera PC socket.

Comment: Just an update: the [Phottix Odin TTL radio triggers come in a Sony/Minolta flavor](http://www.phottix.com/en/studio-accessories/phottix-odin-ttl-flash-trigger-for-sony.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is a radio trigger like the [Cactus v4](http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/product.php?productid=17204) trigger with a [hot shoe adapter](http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/product.php?productid=16892) to provide the interface. I don't know anything about the adapter, there may be others around as well, but the Cactus triggers are okay, not great, but okay, and generally work in a reasonable range for home studio fun (I have them and have used them on studio strobes).

Comment: So there is nothing with a Sony/Minolta fit of repute?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Of the most well known, it appears they're strictly standard hot shoe size. Minolta, in this instance, I think made a bad mistake and Sony has perpetuated.

Comment: Update: obviously, Sony's had a rethink and stopped the perpetuation since their most recent hotshoes are now iso-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel and Phottix radio flash triggers have Sony/Minolta hotshoe versions, but you can just use hotshoe adapters with any manual radio triggers, since TTL communication doesn't matter. If you need TTL over radio the Pixel Kings and Phottix Odins both have Sony/Minolta hotshoe versions (but they obviously don't support the newer Sony iso-compliant hotshoe flash gear).